# How to add MouseEvent inside the Anonymous Class Listener?

Tags: java, swing

So Im making a puzzle game in JFrame, but i dont know how to use MouseEvent and where to put it inside the Anonymous Class Listener. 
And this is my problem.
I need to move the images to the center of the Frame and guess what is the images.

```
    //p5 components(continue frame)
    ImageIcon pic1st = new ImageIcon("C:\\java pics\\w.png");
    JLabel pic1st0 = new JLabel(pic1st);
    JLabel level = new JLabel("Level:" + l);
    JLabel score = new JLabel("Score:" + s);
    JLabel time = new JLabel("Time:" + t);
```

and the Anonymous Class Listener

//This is the part of my code where i want to put the MouseEvent.

```
continue1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            f.add(p5);
            f.remove(p20);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.revalidate();
            f.repaint();
        }
    });
//Where to put the MouseEvent here?
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There is plenty of documentation out there including tutorials and working examples! I think `ActionListener` is not related to `MouseListener` except that they share the superclass `EventListener`. Add your mouse event handlers to the component (frame or panel) you want to monitor. Will start you here in [javadoc for component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener(java.awt.event.MouseListener))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a MouseEvent here? Do you need to put an image under the mouse? You say you're centering it...anyway, the way to properly track mouse events is to add a `MouseAdapter` or `MouseListener` to the component where you need to track MouseEvents. See [How to write a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: I mean there are some part of the images that are randomly place in the frame and then I need to put it in the center to see what is the picture then guess it. So it is possible to add MouseEvent inside the Anonymous Class Listener?

Comment: No - MouseListeners are separate classes that need to be added to a component - the same way you added the ActionListener. You only need a MouseListener, though, if you need to track the actual position of the mouse or track clicks on a non-button component.